# convert text to UTF16 for send sms

Tags: c#, utf

hi i am using sms api to send sms in thai language , for that i need to convert my string to UTF , for that i used this online converter
[convert string to utf](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter)

my sample string -
เป็นรหัสผ่านใช้ได้ครั้งเดียวของคุณ. ยินดีต้อนรับสู่ USmileShop!
and result something like this - \u0034\u0035\u0032\u0036 \u0e40\u0e1b\u0e47\u0e19\  so on.

but when i am trying to convert samething in c#

```
string teststring = "เป็นรหัสผ่านใช้ได้ครั้งเดียวของคุณ. ยินดีต้อนรับสู่ USmileShop!";
 SoapHexBinary hexBinary = new SoapHexBinary(System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(teststring));
```

its give value something like this - 0E400E1B0E47
without \u .
how can i get \u from c# , any help or suggestion .

Comment: Are you sure your SMS API requires text in the format `\uxxxx`? That would be very unusual. Also, that's not UTF-16 format, but just a representation of it using only ASCII characters. If an API description says UTF-16 is required, then you should be able to just pass a C# string directly to it, since C# strings are already in UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: yes API required string like =%00%4F%00%54%00%50%  if sms is not in English language so if i have \u i can simply replace with % and its working fine as i tested with sms api .

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to encode it as UTF rather than in a encoded URL-string. 
The command you need would be the following.

```
var urlEscape = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(teststring);
```